# DateTimeFormatter java

Tags: java, datetime, time-format

I have problems with my datetime formater:

```
     private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm")
```

I want a given LocalDateTime

2015-04-12T20:00

to be printed as

12-04-2015 20:00

but my time is always printed as 08:00, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"`. Lowercase `hh` is 12-hour hours, `HH` is 24-hour hours.

Please refer to the documentation of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), where there is a list of all formatting and parsing formats.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow 24 hours format to achieve this. So use HH instead of hh. Here goes the code

> private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
>               DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

For more details on different formats for DateTimeFormatter, look [here](https://icl.googleusercontent.com/https://icl.googleusercontent.com/?lite_url=http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html&ei=fTIgVcno&lc=en-IN&s=1#a.fullDateTime--)